# why does my html link with css but not my img

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<h2>A few facts about the world we live in</h2>
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg/640px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 300;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Georgia;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I have saved my html and css in the same folder. My css file is named as stylesheet.css.

I am able to edit  but not  through my css file which means my css file and html are linked but I somehow can't seem to edit images. Somebody help me!

Comment: Try to download the image and reference it locally as CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

the issue is your units.  300 of what?  You need to add a % or px or em.

```
img{
  width:300px;
}
```

Fiddle with 300px
https://jsfiddle.net/jL7Lqfv8/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your CSS is being pulled in? Check your network tab in your browser to ensure it is. Also, try giving some units to the image width:
        img {
            width: 300px;
        }